# Makefile runs code that a compile-time #if says it shouldn't

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to compile my code on Linux and created a simple make file.
In one of my headers, there is a compile-time conditional #include for a file that emulates Unix's dirent.h.

I put this include in a `#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)`, and yet g++ happily includes the file, which results in endless errors.

The whole block looks like this:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) 
#include "dirent.h"
#define strncasecmp _strnicmp 
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <utime.h>
#endif
```

Is there any obvious reason for this to happen?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the #include <dirent.h> that happens to find "." in the include-path before the "proper" location.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Oh, you are correct! thanks. Now I just feel silly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, given the comments: Don't call your "compatibility header" `"dirent.h"` but something like `"dirent_compat.h"` or `"dirent_win.h"`.

Alternatively, don't add current directory to the include path for system includes (you really shouldn't have `<...>` includes in current directory anyway)